# Remove last comma from string that doesn't end with comma in Java 8

Tags: java, string

I have input string:

```
String myString = "test, test1, must not be null";
```

I want to remove last comma in this string

Expected output:

```
test, test1 must not be null
```

Any idea if this can be done using StringUtils?

Comment: For the next time: questions that show *your own* effort to solve the problem are simply more appreciated than those "here are requirements" that implicitly expect that other people do the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option which uses a negative lookahead to target the final comma in the string:

```
String myString = "test, test1, must not be null";
myString = myString.replaceAll(",(?!.*,)", "");
System.out.println(myString);

test, test1 must not be null
```

### Demo

Comment: yes, but you need DOTALL to handle newlines

Comment: @PatrickParker Did the OP mention the need to match across newlines?

Comment: no, but it deserves mention when introducing an assumption (e.g. must not have newlines) that was not stated in the original question. my comment has served that purpose, just that

Answer (score 15):

You can also use a `StringBuilder`:

```
String result = new StringBuilder(myString)
    .deleteCharAt(myString.lastIndexOf(",")).toString()

//"test, test1 must not be null" is the result
```

You may need to wrap that in `if(myString.lastIndexOf(",") >= 0)` to avoid index out of bounds exceptions

Answer (score 2):

With a regex, you can replace the last `,` using this for example:

```
String result = myString.replaceAll(",([^,]*)$", "$1");
```

In substance, it looks for a comma, followed by 0 or more non comma characters until the end of the string and replaces that sequence with the same thing, without the comma.

Comment: No need to use a capture group here.

Answer (score 2):

This will work fine:

```
String myString = "test, test1, must not be null";
    int index = myString.lastIndexOf(",");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(myString);
    if(index>0) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(index);
    }

    myString = sb.toString();

    System.out.println(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you fix the problem upstream in the code? instead of adding a comma after each element of the list, put it in front of each element of the list except the first element. Then you don't need to resort to these hacky solutions.

Comment: The last comma which the OP wants to remove is not a dangling final comma, implying that bad concatenation happened.  Rather, it seem to be part of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `String` class `substring()` function.

```
int index=str.lastIndexOf(',');
if(index==0) {//end case
    str=str.substring(1);
} else {
    str=str.substring(0, index)+ str.substring(index+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
int index=str.lastIndexOf(',');
if(index==0) {//end case
    str=str.substring(1);
} else {
    str=str.substring(0, index)+ str.substring(index+1);
}
```